# Nav-Menu not showing up

Tags: php, functions, menus, navigation

I would love for somebody to please help me because somewhere I am really miss understanding what WordPress is telling me.

Alright so within my header.php I have the following code.

```
<div class="navigation navigation-top" id="menu-nav">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
<li><a href="">Home</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
</li>       

<li class="menu-search"><form method="get" class="form-search" action="">
<input type="text" name="s" class="input-medium" placeholder="">
<input type="hidden" name="site_section" value="all" />
</form></li>
</div>
```

Now I am not sure what I am doing wrong from the above point onward as I pretty much followed what the guide says on the WordPress wiki. The content below is what is shown in my functions.php file.

```
//Navigation Bar
register_nav_menus(
array( 'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'ThemeName' ) )
);
```

Any help in what I am doing wrong is really really appreciated I have just started coding with WordPress so bare with me.

First is my menu ( Shows as being registered and has content set to be inside of it. ) bottom is my navbar with no content on it at all.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the menu, you need to set it up in the wordpress admin side.

1. Go to Appearance -> Menus You should see a "Manage Locations" tab.
2. Select it. You should see your "Main Menu" location.
3. Choose the menu that you created there.
4. Select Save Changes.

Since you used "theme-location" to set up drawing it, you need to set a menu to your theme location to actually draw it.

(note) If you have not yet created a menu, you should use the "Edit Menus" tab to create one so that you can associate it as outlined above.

Comment: Check update, I am already doing these things.. and the content is still not displaying on my nav-bar.

Comment: Strange. It looks good here. Personally, I'd try changing it to main_menu instead of main-menu to see if that does anything. If not, I'd then try invoking it via `wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'dfasd') );` just to see if it shows up that way. I'd also check the html source to make sure it is not being blocked out by a bad tag... mostly because what I see above looks right.